# Table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]I am writing a thesis in APA style. My current Table of contents read as 
I INTRODUCTION

but I wanted to write

CHAPTER I-INTRODUCTION.

Could you please tell me how to format it. 
Thanks
Palai

I used document class as "report". The style file I am using is as follow:

```
\parindent 0.8cm    % set paragraph indentation to 0.8cm
\oddsidemargin 16mm %% changed from 10 to 16
\evensidemargin 0mm
\marginparwidth 40pt
\marginparsep 10pt
\textwidth 144mm
\topmargin -5mm %% ratnkar changed from -12 to -5mm
\headheight 5mm
\headsep 15mm %% ratnakar changed from 5 to 15 mm
%--\topskip 0pt
\textheight 221mm %% ratnakar changed from 245 to 221mm
%\footskip 0pt
%%
%% Line Spacing...
%%

\usepackage{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.66}
   % \setstretch{1.66}     % Double Space (Latex adds 20% to this)
   % \setstretch{1.24}     % 1 1/2 Space
   % \setstretch{1}        % Single Space
%\def\arraystretch{1.2} % Spacing for tabular data


%%
%% Indentation... Stolen from indentfirst.sty by David Carlisle
%%
%%
%% Make the first line of all sections etc be indented by the usual
%% paragraph indentation.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{25pt}

%%
%% Store Thesis Info in a set of variable that will
%% be used in the \maketitle and abstract environment
%% (\author and \date are also used)
%%

\newcommand \degree[1]{\gdef \@degree{#1}}
\newcommand \dept[1]{\gdef \@dept{#1}}
\newcommand \advisor[1]{\gdef \@advisor{#1}}
\newcommand \committee[1]{\gdef \@committee{#1}}

%%
%% redefine the title-page format
%%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
  {\begin{titlepage}% Start of Titlepage
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 0\p@
  \begin{singlespace}
  \begin{center}%
    \vskip 3em%
   {\LARGE \bf \@title \par} % Sets the Title layout.
      \vskip 4em%
      {\large
      \lineskip .75em%
      \vspace{3.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}% This starts the table enviroment.
    \@degree \\
    \vspace{35mm} \\
    \@dept
    \vspace{5mm} \\
    \Large
    \@author \\
    \vspace{5mm} \\

    \@date
      \end{tabular}\par}% This ends the table enviroment.
      \vskip 1.5em%
    %{\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  %\@thanks
  %\vfil\null
  \vfill
  %\begin{singlespace}
  %\begin{list}
  %{\leftmargin 0.5in\topsep 0pt\partopsep 0pt}
  %\item
  %\@committee
  %\end{list}
  %\vfill
  \end{singlespace}
  \end{titlepage}   % End of Titlepage
  %\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  %\let\thanks\relax\let\maketitle\relax
  %\gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}
  %\gdef\@background{}\gdef\@committee{}\gdef\advisor{}
  }



%%
%% redefine the Abstract Format
%%
\def\@absapp{ABSTRACT}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{
    \begin{center}
   { \LARGE \bf ABSTRACT}
    \end{center}
}{}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}


%%
%% redefine the format for chapter
%%

\def\@chapapp{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\clearpage\global\@topnum\z@
  %\@afterindentfalse
   \renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
     \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[2]{

 {
 %\parindent 0pt \raggedright
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \begin{center}\huge \bf  \@chapapp{} \thechapter \par
 \vskip 0in \fi \huge \bf #1\par
 \nobreak \vskip 0.4in

\end{center}

\parindent 0.8cm
\thispagestyle{plain} %Set for final draft ##
%\thispagestyle{fancy}  %Set for draft printing with version
% NB:- USE OF "##" REFERS TO NOTE AT START OF thesis.tex

}}



%%
%% redefine the format for captions
%%
%\newcommand{\captionsmall}[1]{\caption{\sf \footnotesize #1}} % NA
\renewcommand\figurename{\sl \footnotesize Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{\sl \footnotesize Table}

%%
%% redefine the format for false-chapter
%%
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{{\parindent 0pt
 \raggedright
 \huge \bf #1\par
 \nobreak \vskip 0.5in} }



%%
%% redefine the format for section
%%

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{10}{\z@}
 {-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}{\LARGE \bf}}



%%
%% redefine the format for subsection
%%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{10}{\z@}
 {-3ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}{\large\bf}}


%%
%% redefine the format for footnotes
%%
%%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}




%% redefine the name of reference section
%%

\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{\section*{References\@mkboth
 {References}{References}}\list
 {[\Roman{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

% Bibtex database file: "references.bib"
}
%%
%% redefine the chapter-level toc entry to include dots.
%%

\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{
    \vspace{\baselineskip} \bfseries
    \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.3em}{#1}{#2}
    %\newlength(\NumberWidth}
    %\settowidth{\NumberWidth}{#1}
    %\@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{\NumberWidth}{#1}{#2}
    \normalfont }
%
\newcommand{\l@appendix}[2]{
%    \vspace
    {\baselineskip} \bfseries
    \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.3in}{#1}{#2}
    \normalfont }

%%
%% redefine the heading for toc
%%

 %

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@restonecolfalse
 \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{\Large \begin{center}TABLE OF CONTENTS \end{center}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
 \@mkboth{\begin{center}Table of Contents}{Table of Contents}}
 \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}





%%
%% redefine the heading for lof
%%

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\@restonecolfalse
 \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{\begin{center} LIST OF FIGURES \end{center}
 \@mkboth
 {List of Figures}{List of Figures}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}\@starttoc{lof}\if@restonecol
 \twocolumn\fi}




%%
%% redefine the heading of lot
%%


\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\@restonecolfalse
 \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{\begin{center}LIST OF TABLES \end{center}
 \@mkboth
 {List of Tables}{List of Tables}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}\@starttoc{lot}\if@restonecol
 \twocolumn\fi}

%%
%% Appendix Junk required by Grad School
%%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \setcounter{section}{0}%
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
    \renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
            \thispagestyle{plain}%
            \global\@topnum\z@
            \@afterindentfalse
            \secdef\@myappendix\@schapter}
    }

\def\@myappendix[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}%
                              {\protect\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Comment: Only in the toc or everywhere?  Many title related issues can be addressed with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Modify the definition of `\l@chapter` such that it contains `\@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.3em}{CHAPTER #1}{#2}`.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title for your question and try to create a minimal working example instead of providing so much code a potential answerer has to go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the definition of `\l@chapter` such that it contains `\@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.3em}{CHAPTER #1}{#2}`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\ch@name{}

\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \bfseries
    \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{7em}{\renewcommand\ch@name{CHAPTER} #1}{#2}%
    \normalfont
}

\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\ch@name\ #1\hfil--}%
  \renewcommand\ch@name{}%
  \space
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Unnumbered}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Unnumbered}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! it did work. Could you please tell me how to introduce a hyphen as "CHAPTER I-INTRODUCTION". Thank you very much!

Comment: @R.Palai See the updated answer.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot! When I modify as you suggested, it is adding CHAPTER to all the sections in my content. Please at my Table of Contents attached to my question. I just want to write for only chapters as CHAPTER I-INTRODUCTION. Currently, it reads as I INTRODUCTION. Do you think the main tex file would be helpful?

Comment: @R.Palai See the updated answer.  By the way, it is kind of rude to change the requirements after the question was answered.

Comment: Hi Henri, I am sorry, I didn't change my question and requirements. Please check my question and Table of Contents. I thanked you thinking it solved my problem, but I didn't realize that it adds CHAPTER to all the heading in table of content.